# i tried loading html page to div using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

trying to load html page to div using jQuery ajax im pretty sure it's right but i don't know why exactly it's not working.
that's my code:

```
 <div class="second">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("button").on("click",function(){
    $('#second').load($(this).data("page"));
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue is related to your Selector. You are using an ID Selector versus a Class Selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".second").load($(this).data("page"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-page="page-2.html">Get Page 2</button>

<div class="second"></div>
```

This will work properly as it uses a Class selector to target he proper `<div>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$('#second')
```

To:

```
$('.second')
```

As second is a class, not an id.